# LibGDX - Image width is not set to resetting to zero when full width

Tags: java, libgdx, software-engineering

I am making a progress bar for showing the players current experience. However I have come around to a bug, which appears when the player is maxing out his experience and then is getting a new level. In the ideal world my code should reset the progress bar image width (which is a Scene2D image btw), but for some reason it is not setting the image width to zero, but is setting it to its full width instead, which I can't seem to understand why. I hope anyone can help me.

I have provided my code below, and also uploaded a video on youtube with my bug - [Video of the bug](https://youtu.be/KH29N2jDmxE)

The method below is the one I use to change the experience progress bar width as well as the experience.

```
public void changeLevelExperience(int gainedExperience) {
    float maxExpDividedInPixels = 131f / this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().maxExperience;

    this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentExperience += gainedExperience;

    if (this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentExperience >= this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().maxExperience) {
        this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentLevel++;
        this.currentLevelLabel.setText(this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentLevel + "");
        //TODO: Another arrangement for the experience needs to be made.
        this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().maxExperience += 35;
        this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentExperience = 0;
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentExperience + "");
    }

    this.levelProgressBar.setWidth((int) (maxExpDividedInPixels * this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager().currentExperience * this.scaleFactor));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. It was with some help from people at a facebook group. :)

The bug occours, because my Scene2D [Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) (the level progress bar) was a child of a scene2D [Table](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html). And the Table was initially set to have a column width to the width of the image, when it was at its largest size. This width was now set to zero, as I have done in the code below.

```
table.add(this.levelProgressBar).width(0 * this.scaleFactor).height(10 * this.scaleFactor);
```

Apparently the Image width is reset to the tables column width,when it is set to the width of zero.
Thank you all which tried to help me. It was really appreciated :)

Comment: That (sort of) makes sense (though it's odd that LibGDX will "helpfully" has arbitrary behavior when setting the image width to 0). You might also just special-case 0 and just hide the image instead.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally used `ProgressBar` yet, but it looks like the [right way](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.html) to set the current percentage is using [`setValue(float)`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.html#setValue-float-), not `setWidth(float)`. I'd start with that.

---

Also, saving your `GameManager` object in a local variable instead of writing `this.GAME.gameScreen.getGameManager()` 10 times will make the code a lot more legible ;)

Comment: I must have been bad at explaining. The progress bar is not a ProgressBar Widget, but an Image widget. That is why I use setWidth(). :) - I think I have found the bug now. It seems that it was resetting, but it was an image inside of a table, and it was resetting to the table column width, which was set to its current max width. Now it is set to zero every time, because the inital value of the table column width is set to zero. Thanks for you help though.. it is really appreciated :)

Comment: Ah, whoops, I misread the question. Sorry about that!